# Extending an API in C in a flexible and unobtrusive way

Tags: c, api, static-methods, abstraction

I'm trying to add some additional functionality to an API. However, I'd like these additional functions to be in an external library of mine and not mixed with the original library's code.

The problem comes when I need to access static functions of the mentioned API from my functions. Of course I can't, so the only solution I see is either to copy these functions' code into my API or to make them non-static in the original API. Both are not too good options for me for obvious reasons.

More precisely:

```
original_api.c
  void some_function() -> uses some_helper_function()  
  static some_helper_function()

my_api_extension.c
  void some_extended_function() -> needs to use some_helper_function from original_api.c, but can't
```

Could you suggest which would be the most flexible way to handle this?

I'd like to point out that it's related to C only, not C++.

Comment: It's getting really messy. The only viable solution I see is to write my code in a header which I'll include in the original library...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make the functions static.
2. Create an extern `struct` with pointers to these functions. Declare it in a separate `#include` file, available to the extension, but not to the entire world.
3. Use the `struct` in your extension.

Something like this:

```
// in the private header
typedef struct
{
  void (*p_myfunc1)(int);
  int (*p_myfunc2)(void);
} privateAPI_t;
extern privateAPI_t privateAPI;

// in the library
static void myfunc1(int);
static int myfunc2(void);

privateAPI_t privateAPI = { myfunc1, myfunc2 };

// in the extension
#include <privateAPI.h>
...
privateAPI.p_myfunc1(privateAPI.p_myfunc2());
```

Comment: That's nothing short of great!

Comment: All compiles OK, but I get null pointers for the functions. The `privateAPI_t privateAPI = { myfunc1, myfunc2 };` is in a SO library, whilst the `privateAPI.p_myfunc1(privateAPI.p_myfunc2());` is in a app that uses this library. Any ideas what to do?

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong, but I fixed it by doing an explicit dynamic init. That is, rather than using an external variable, I'm using a init function in the library that does that at runtime. The important thing is that it's working. Thanks n.m.!